# Getting this error: "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException"; may be a fundamental issue

Tags: java, encoding

I guess I can preface this with the assignment? [image: assignment]

In any case, I barely understand the assignment, Im gonna be honest. Been truly freeballing, but I've gotten it down to this:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class TimeTravel
{


   static final double STUDENT_DISCOUNT = .50;
   static final double EMPLOYEE_DISCOUNT = .25;

    /** 
   * Discounts described   
   *
   * @param args Command line arguments (not used).
   */ 

   public static void main(String[] args) {


      Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
      //double ticketcode;



      System.out.println("Enter ticketcode: ");
      //ticketcode = userInput.nextDouble();
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      String ticketcode = input.nextLine();
      System.out.println((char)Integer.parseInt(ticketcode));
      int tcode = Integer.parseInt(ticketcode);

      //String s = Double.toString(ticketcode);


      if (tcode <= 26) {

         System.out.println("*** Invalid ticket code ***"
            + "\nTicket code must have at least 26 characters.");
      }

      else {


         System.out.println("Time: ");
         System.out.println(ticketcode.substring(0, 4));

         System.out.println("Date: ");
         System.out.println(ticketcode.substring(5, 12));

         System.out.println("Category: ");
         System.out.println(ticketcode.substring(0, 4));

         System.out.println("Seat: ");
         System.out.println(ticketcode.substring(27, 29));

         System.out.println("Itinerary: ");
         System.out.println(ticketcode.substring(30, 54));

         double price = Double.parseDouble(ticketcode);
         DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");
         System.out.println("Price: " + df.format((ticketcode.substring(14, 22))));

         System.out.println(ticketcode.substring(0, 4));
         System.out.println("Cost: ");




         System.out.println("Prize Number: ");
         System.out.println(ticketcode.substring(0, 4));   



      }
   }
}
```

every comment within the main body is pretty much my rambling.

Comment: and what is your question or problem?

Comment: java!=javascript

Comment: This is not javascript

Comment: According to the image, the input is a single long line of **text**. Which part of [`parseInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) failing for **text** such as **`153012152090s02498990018B....`** is confusing you? Especially since the **documentation**, i.e. javadoc, says: *Throws `NumberFormatException` if the string does not contain a parsable integer.* Does that look like a parsable integer to you?

Answer (score 0):

If you insert into your standard input(in your case `ticketcode`) Non integer character then `Integer.parseInt(ticketcode)` will throw `NumberFormatException`. This is because non integer input can not parsed.